# memory allocated by jdbc driver for pl/sql function result

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql

According to the "[Oracle JDBC Memory Management](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/memory.pdf)" document Oracle jdbc driver allocates `char[]` buffer when statement is parsed.
Buffer size is calculated based on the maximum size possible for the row data returned by the query.
For example for `SELECT NAME FROM TAB` statement where `NAME` is `VARCHAR2(40)`, 40*2 bytes = 80 bytes will be allocated.

How big the buffer will be if row data is a function with return `varchar2`?
For example:

```
select FOO from dual;
```

where FOO is

```
create or replace function FOO
return varchar2 is
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but if the doc says that the jdbc will allocate the maximum result possible, in this case will be 32767 (max in PL/SQL).

Answer (score 2):

I created a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION TEMP_ADAM_FUNC RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'TEST';
END;
```

And I queried it as follows:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT TEMP_ADAM_FUNC FROM DUAL");
results.next();
results.getString(1);
```

After running this through the debugger, you can see that the driver has allocated a substantial amount of memory:

[image]

The driver has, in fact, allocated ***65535*** characters for a `VARCHAR2` column.

I ran another query:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL");
results.next();
results.getString(1);
```

I confirmed the size of the `DUMMY` column using this query:

```
SELECT
  DATA_TYPE,
  DATA_LENGTH
FROM
  ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE
  TABLE_NAME = 'DUAL' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'DUMMY'
```

This query yielded up `'VARCHAR2'` and `1` respectively.

However, in this case, the driver allocated ***4096*** characters:

[image]

I am not terribly sure what is governing this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off on a tangent from your question...

As mentioned on page 5 of the white paper you linked to, if you can use an `OracleStatement` then you can use [`defineColumnType`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleStatement.html#defineColumnType_int__int__int_) to limit the size, and therefore the amount of memory reserved for, a column.

So you can specify a smaller size than the default when the size isn't fixed as in your function call, or if you're return a ref cursor; which may save a significant amount of memory (since you may be getting 32k - or even more based on Adam's investigation - multiplied by the number of rows you're prefetching). You can also specify the size for columns you do know the size of, which can save a trip to tbe DB for those to be looked up when the statement is prepared. In either case, if you set the number too low and retrieve a column with a longer value than you allowed, you'll get an error.